# How to check-out/check-in a file into a ClearCase snapshot view using an Ant script?

Tags: ant, clearcase

I would like to update a file under ClearCase source control. This needs to happen from an Ant script.

I have created a snapshot view for this purpose. `ccupdate` updates it just fine.

I have tried using `cccheckout` but it fails with the following error `cleartool: Error: To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view.`.

Is there a way to check-out a file in a snapshot view, replace it and check-in the new version? If this involves creating/switching to an activity, please include this in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apache Ant ClearCase Tasks](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/clearcase.htmlhttps://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/clearcase.html) (2003!) are pre-UCM area.
That means they have no notion of "UCM view" (snapshot or dynamic) or activities.

If you are staying with ant, you could try (not tested) a tasks library like [clearantlib](http://clearantlib.sourceforge.net/), which allows you to execute any cleartool command (with [`ccexec`](http://clearantlib.sourceforge.net/ccexec.html))

That way you can use a [`cleartool setact`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-2-27) in order to set a UCM activity in the UCM view.
Your checkout will proceed only when an activity is set.

Answer (score 1):

As [clearantlib](http://clearantlib.sourceforge.net/) is only a thin wrapper around cleartool command line, you're on your own. Following some snippet of production code for the 'checkout part', that might be helpful for writing your own ant task - otherwise you need to use a bunch of `ant <exec>` parts calling cleartool. Checkout specific versions in a clearcase snapshotview means create and set a configspec. For the update part use ProcessBuilder with the relevant cleartool commands :

```
  /**
   *
   * @param modulinfos
   * @param jobid
   * @param snapshotpath
   */
  private void createConfSpec(ArrayList<String> modulinfos, String jobid, String snapshotpath)
  {
    /*
    element * CHECKEDOUT
    element "/at_vobt2/Foo/.../" v_1_4_00_49a
    element "/at_vobt2/FooBar/.../" v_1_3_02_06c
    element "/at_vobt2/Foo Base/.../" v_1_3_01_28b
    element * /main/LATEST
    load "/vobt2/Foo"
    load "/vobt2/FooBar"
    load "/vobt2/FooBase"
    */

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("element * CHECKEDOUT");
    for (String string : modulinfos)
    {
      sb.append(nl).append("element \"/" + string.split("#")[0] + "/" + string.split("#")[1] + "/.../\" " + string.split("#")[2]);
    }

    sb.append(nl).append("element * /main/LATEST");

    for (String string : modulinfos)
    {
      sb.append(nl).append("load \"/" + string.split("#")[0] + "/" + string.split("#")[1] + "\"");
    }
    sb.append(nl);

    File file = new File(snapshotpath + "\\" + jobid + ".confspec");
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
      writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
      writer.write(sb.toString());
      writer.close();
      getLogger().debug("Create ConfigSpec : " + nl + sb.toString() + "File => " + file.getPath());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param snapshotpath
   * @return
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private boolean checkSnapshotView(String snapshotpath) throws IOException
  {
    boolean isReady = false;
    // use pushd/popd cause cmd doesn't support UNC !
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder
    (
      "cmd", "/c",
      "pushd " + snapshotpath + " && cleartool lsview -l -pro -cview && popd"
    );
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
      sb.append(line).append(nl);
    }
    isReady = !StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(sb.toString(), "cleartool: Error: Cannot get view info for current view");
    getLogger().debug("Check Snapshotview : " + snapshotpath + nl + sb.toString());
    return isReady;
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param jobid
   * @param snapshotpath
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private void createSnapshotView(String jobid, String snapshotpath) throws IOException
  {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder
    (
      "cmd", "/c",
      "cleartool mkview -snapshot -tag " + "snapshot" + jobid + " " + snapshotpath
    );
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
      sb.append(line).append(nl);
    }
    getLogger().debug("Create Snapshotview : " + nl + sb.toString());
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param snapshotpath
   * @param configspecpath
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private void setConfigSpec(String snapshotpath, String configspecpath) throws IOException
  {
    // use pushd/popd cause cmd doesn't support UNC !
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder
    (
      "cmd", "/c",
      "pushd " + snapshotpath + " && cleartool setcs " + configspecpath + " && popd"
    );
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
      sb.append(line).append(nl);
    }
    getLogger().debug("Update Snapshotview : " + nl + sb.toString());
  }
```